# how to find subpart from comma separated value of a column and insert in new rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, logic

Problem:

In database table, one column has few comma separated value, want to find the string and insert into new row by mysql query.

**Example table structure:**

```
| id    value        |
| 1     abcd         |
| 2     xyz,123,abcd |
```

**Output will be**

```
| id   value |
| 1     abcd |
| 2     xyz  |
| 3     123  |
| 4     abcd |
```

Note: id is auto increment. Mysql version 5.7
Don't get idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mysql does not have a function for this you are going to have to write a tokenising procedure to do this and search for mysql split string

Answer (score 0):

You can build a query to return numbers.

```
SELECT 1 AS a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
```

You can join that against itself multiple times to return a bigger range of numbers.

You can then join the results of that against your first table, and use the number with SUBSTRING_INDEX, looking for the comma, and the previous comma. And just insert that value into your 2nd table.

Done it a few times.

Things to watch out for:-

That your number range is sufficient.

That the last value is likely to be repeated. You can exclude this using DISTINCT, or comparing the number to how many commas the initial string contains